# How to convert isolated memory into File Storage in C#?

Tags: c#, filestream, isolatedstorage

Is there anyway to convert Isolated memory to File Storage.
I need a method that can get data from Isolated Storage and then Store it to Files that I have already defined in my program.

Comment: What do you mean by Isolated Storage?

Comment: Do you want to read a file from IsolatedStorage and save to a file at a given path ?

Comment: @Gun Yes I mean Isolated Storage

Comment: @Kurubaran absolutely thats my point

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following example shows how you could read a text file within IsolatedStorage and write to a specific location,

```
string fileContent = string.Empty;

//Read file within IsolatedStorage
using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore((IsolatedStorageScope.Domain | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User), null, null))
{
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(storage.OpenFile("ReadMe.txt", FileMode.Open)))
    {
       fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

//Write to a textfile
File.WriteAllText(@"File path", fileContent);
```